# how to realize peer-to-peer protocole using python socket

Tags: python, sockets

hello I would like to design a peer-to-peer between two nodes A and B, therefore, before node A transmits a data frame, it can scan port B by generating a unique code serving as identifier of the transmission from A to B. this identifier will secure the transmission. But I don't know how to do it in python with socket library. Could someone have good documentation allowing me to set up such a system?